# Files are "executable" after copying to an NTFS external drive using rsync

Tags: linux-mint, rsync, ntfs

I used rsync to copy to a new external drive (that came new already NTFS formatted), with a script like:

```
SRC="/home/me/"
DRV="/media/me/maxone"
echo "Syncing $SRC to $DRV"
DST="${DRV}/home"
rsync -avi --exclude-from='/home/me/scripts/excl.txt' --delete
--modify-window=1 --no-perms --no-o --no-g --no-links $SRC $DST
```

All seemed to go well until I noticed that all the files on the drive seemed to have the executable attribute. I want to use the NTFS format so that I can access the files from different platforms. How can I get around this so that the files look normal i.e. if I copied them back from the drive? Can I do this with rsync, or do I have to reformat this NTFS drive with different settings so that files are not executable by default, if so how?

The drive shows this type/info:

```
$ df -T
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      fuseblk  488383488 279798784 208584704  58% /media/me/maxone
```

Further:

```
$ mount|grep fuseblk
/dev/sdb1 on /media/me/maxone type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,
user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: NTFS does not understand Linux permissions, so it will depend on how the OS is mounting the drive. Reformatting, or using options in rsync, will not make any difference.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Can you elaborate? How can I find out the details of the mounting? I'm using Linux Mint.

Comment: What I meant by mounting is the options being used to mount the drive. On my dual-boot system, I add `uid=1000, gid=1000` when I mount my Windows partition, so that all files are owned by me. If you type `mount | grep ntfs`, you'll see exactly how the drive was mounted on Mint.

Comment: @ajgringo619 So adding uid=1000,gid=1000 to the mount options, and remounting will fix this problem? (May have to recopy the files?)

Comment: No, that just changes how Linux sees the owner/group (and that's for every file/directory on the partition). You can play around with umasks/dmasks (as mount options), but you can't use Linux permissions on NTFS partitions.